# German visitor visa for my Indian parents and brother

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, schengen-visas

I'm going to invite my parents and brother to Germany for a visit of two weeks.
I will send them the invitation; I earn a decent salary and am able to share the cost for them.

1. Should I invite them and also show the sponsorship (Verpflichtungserklärung) for both my parents and brother?
2. Do my parents need to demonstrate their own financial ability?
3. My brother works in my uncle's business and he doesn't have payslips to support his own financial claims. Can my parents show that they also support my brother financially?

Comment: I guess what you really want to show is that your parents and your brother will return after those two weeks. For that, they need to show (financial or other) attachment or security in India.

Comment: Financial status and asset securities are imp thnks